# Ratio of segments formed by intersection of three cevians

Tags: geometry, inequality, contest-math, triangles, means

ABC is a triangle and P some point inside it. Cevians AP, BP, CP cross the opposite sides at A',B' and C' respectively.

What is the minimum value the following expression can accomplish:

`(1+2*PA'/PA)(1+2*PB'/PB)(1+2*PC'/PC)` ?

---

The solution is 8, when each ratio is 1/2 (meaning that is a centroid) but I'm having trouble reaching that.

Now from the ratio of areas APB, BPC, CPA and the whole triangle ABC we get respectively:

`Pa/P = A'P/A'A`, `Pb/P = B'P/B'B`, `Pa/P = C'P/C'C`, and summing this i get

`1 = PA'/(PA' + PA) + PB'/(PB' + PB) + PC'/(PC' + PC)`

Does from here directly follows some relation to the wanted expression fully algebraically, and if so how? Or should I still consider them as being in the triangle?

Replacing PA'/PA=x PB'/PB=y PC'/PC=z I get

`1 = 1/(1 + 1/x) + 1/(1 + 1/y) + 1/(1 + 1/z)`, and the wanted expression as `(1+2x)(1+2y)(1+2z)`

---

I also tried:

`4 = 1 + x/(1+x) + 1 + y/(1+y) + 1 + z/(1+z)`

`4 = (1+2x)/(1+x) + (1+2y)/(1+y) + (1+2z)/(1+z)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the substitution $ a = \frac{1}{ 1 + \frac{1}{x} }$, or that $ x = \frac{a}{1-a}$, and $ 1 + 2x = \frac{ 1+a}{1-a}$.

Rephrasing what you already have

> WTS $ \prod \frac{ 1 + a } { 1 - a } \geq 8 $ subject to $ a + b + c = 1$.

This is much easier to work with, give it a try.

> Jensen's on the product: Show that $ \ln \frac{ 1+a}{1-a}$ is convex, so $\prod \frac{1+a}{1-a} \geq ( \frac{ 1 + 1/3 } { 1 - 1/3} ) ^3 = 8 $.

> AM-GM: substituting in $ a+b+c = 1$,  $\prod \frac{ (a+b) + (c+a) } { (b+c)}  \geq \prod \frac{ 2 \sqrt{ (a+b)(c+a) }} { (b+c) } = 8.$

Comment: Thanks. I don't get this ||convexity|| argument, any application of means or C-S to produce the solution? Also do we have to check at the end that solution is achievable, because there might be other (inter)constrains on these geometrical objects.

Comment: @croraf A) It's the standard Jensens' applied to product, hence taking of logs, namely $\log (ABC) = \log A +\log B + \log C$. B) As it turns out, there is an almost immediate AM-GM solution when you substitute $a+b+c=1$. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? C) Yes, we have to check that the minimum is achieved. You already did so by saying that it is achieved when $P$ is the centroid.

Comment: Yes, I've now somehow managed to push to the solution. I will post it as my answer in 5 min.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the following from the question I managed to push to the solution.

Replacing PA'/PA=x PB'/PB=y PC'/PC=z I get

`1 = 1/(1 + 1/x) + 1/(1 + 1/y) + 1/(1 + 1/z)` [1], and the wanted expression as

`(1+2x)(1+2y)(1+2z)`

---

[1] can be written as `1 = xy + yz + xz + 2xyz`. [3]

Also from [1] and H-A `1 <= (x+1)/4 + (y+1)/4 + (z+1)/4`
that is `1 <= x + y + z` [4]

Now using [3] and [4] we have

`(1+2x)(1+2y)(1+2z) = 1 + 2x + 2y + 2z + 4xy + 4xz + 4yz + 8xyz = 1 + 2x + 2y + 2z + 4 >= 7`

I did it on the paper, but then found mistake and it dropped from 8 to 7 :D hahaha

Comment: I guess I cannot apply the H-A inequallity partially on the three terms as the minimum cannot be symultaneously achieved.